# How do I call diamondCut (EIP-2535) from another contract?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to call execute the diamondCut function using another contract, but it keeps getting reverted, even though all the facet addresses and respective function selectors exist and are included in the call. I'm trying to do the following:

- Remove 3 functions, each function is in a separate facet, using the cutSomeDiamonds function in this contract

The interfaces used are in https://github.com/mudgen/diamond-1-hardhat/tree/main/contracts/interfaces

```
contract ExecuteDiamondCuts {

    address CONTRACT_ADDRESS = 0xblahblah; // dummy address
    string[] functionsToRemove;

    constructor() {
        functionsToRemove.push("exampleFunctionA(address)");
        functionsToRemove.push("exampleFunctionB(uint)");
        functionsToRemove.push("exampleFunctionC()");
    }
    
    function cutSomeDiamonds() external {
        IDiamondLoupe _loupe = IDiamondLoupe(CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

        IDiamondCut.FacetCut[] memory _facetCuts = new IDiamondCut.FacetCut[](functionsToRemove.length);

        for (uint i=0; i<functionsToRemove.length; i++) {
            
            address facetWithFn = _loupe.facetAddress(bytes4(keccak256(bytes((functionsToRemove[i])))));
            bytes4[] memory _fnSelectors = new bytes4[](1);
            _fnSelectors[0] = bytes4(keccak256(bytes((functionsToRemove[i]))));

            IDiamondCut.FacetCut memory _facetCut = IDiamondCut.FacetCut({
                facetAddress: facetWithFn, // facet address
                action: IDiamondCut.FacetCutAction.Remove, // action
                functionSelectors: _fnSelectors // array of fn selectors
            });
            _facetCuts[i] = _facetCut;
        }

        (bool success,) = CONTRACT_ADDRESS.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "diamondCut(FacetCut[],address,bytes)", 
                _facetCuts,
                address(0),
                "0x"
            )
        );
        require(success);
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work until `require(success);` which got reverted.

Comment: First, `"exampleFunctionB(uint)"` should be `"exampleFunctionB(uint256)"`. Second, why the use of `delegatecall` at the end? Is this contract another facet?

Comment: Noted on the uint. Only the contract owner is allowed to diamondCut, hence I'm using delegatecall instead of calling the function directly.

Comment: With delegatecall you're acting on the ExecuteDiamondCuts contract itself, that's the problem. What you should be doing is make this contract allowed to diamondCut, and use `call` instead of `delegateCall`. In any case, I don't see a reason to use a intermediary contract for this operation, you can make the diamondCut call directly from your account.